# OpenJPA Wrong order for delete of child when deleting parent

Tags: jpa, openjpa

The order of deletes for OpenJPA 2.3.x are happening in the wrong order and I can't figure out why.

Given these JPA mappings

```
// grandparent
@Entity
@Table(name = "three_phase_motor_input")
public class ThreePhaseMotorInput implements IThreePhaseMotorInput, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, targetEntity = UnapprovedThreePhaseMotor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unapproved_id")
    private IThreePhaseMotor unapprovedMotor;

// parent
@Entity
@Table(name = "unapproved_three_phase_motor")
public class UnapprovedThreePhaseMotor extends ThreePhaseMotor {
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = UnapprovedThreePhaseWire.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "motor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
    private List<IThreePhaseWire> wires;


// child - Abstract
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class ThreePhaseWire implements IThreePhaseWire, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

// child concrete
@Entity
@Table(name = "unapproved_three_phase_wire")
public class UnapprovedThreePhaseWire extends ThreePhaseWire {
```

Order of SQL statements in log file when setting unapprovedMotor in grandparent to null

```
 572353115 UPDATE three_phase_motor_input SET status = ?, version = ?, approved_id = ?, unapproved_id = ? WHERE id = ? AND version = ? [params=(int) 1, (int) 8, (null) null, (null) null, (long) 896, (int) 7]
 1683522521 DELETE FROM unapproved_three_phase_motor WHERE id = ? AND version = ? [params=(long) 209938, (int) 1]
 446470297 DELETE FROM unapproved_three_phase_wire WHERE id = ? [params=(long) 1394]
```

This causes a foreign key constraint error since the child still exists when the parent delete statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I never used OpenJPA but it seems to me that problem can be solved with arrangement on cascading you should check that.