# OpenJPA - Nested OneToMany relationships merge issue

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Posting this here as I wasn't seeing much interest here: http://www.java-forums.org/jpa/96175-openjpa-one-many-within-one-many-merge-problems.html

Trying to figure out if this is a problem with OpenJPA or something I may be doing wrong...

I'm facing a problem when trying to use OpenJPA to update an Entity that contains a One to Many relationship to another Entity, that has a One to Many relationship to another.  Here's a quick example of what I'm talking about:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School {

    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Collection<ClassRoom> classRooms;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "classroom")
public class ClassRoom {

    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "room_number")
    protected String roomNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    protected School school;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classRoom", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Collection<Desk> desks;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "desk")
public class Desk {

    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id")
    protected ClassRoom classRoom;

}
```

In the SchoolService class, I have the following update method:

```
    @Transactional
    public void update(School school) {
        em.merge(school);
    }
```

I'm trying to remove a Class Room from the School.  I remove it from the classRooms collection and call update.  I'm noticing if the Class Room has no desks, there are no issues. But if the Class Room has desks, it throws a constraint error as it seems to try to delete the Class Room first, then the Desks.  (There is a foreign key constraint for the classroom_id column)

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there some setting I'm missing to get it to delete the interior "Desk" instances first before deleting the Class Room instance that was removed?

Any help would be appreciated.  If you need any more info, please just let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: Try clearing the collection: classrom.desks.clear();

Comment: Tried calling clear on the classroom's desks collection before removing it from the school, but it is still trying to remove the classroom before it removes the desks when I update the school.

Comment: This seems to be an openjpa issue. See details here: http://swexplorations.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/openjpa-issues-part-2.html. I am sure I came across it last time I used openjpa and was able to fix it be specifying some configuration property or using some custom openjpa annotation. Can't remember exactly for now. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274433/openjpa-wrong-order-for-delete-of-child-when-deleting-parent

Comment: Good to know it's an issue with openjpa, I haven't come across any settings/annotations that will work for me yet, so any information there would be useful.

Comment: Okay, I think I have recall the solution. Try adding the annotation org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.ForeignKey annotation on the collection mapping: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1936

Comment: I added the ForeignKey annotations to the Desk's join to the ClassRoom (classRoom variable) and the ClassRoom's join to the School (school variable) and that seems to have it working now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various bug reports around FK violations in OpenJPA when cascading remove operations to child entities:

The OpenJPA FAQ notes that the following:

http://openjpa.apache.org/faq.html#reorder

> **Can OpenJPA reorder SQL statements to satisfy database foreign key
>   constraints?**
>
> Yes. OpenJPA can reorder and/or batch the SQL statements using
>   different configurable strategies. The default strategy is capable of
>   reordering the SQL statements to satisfy foreign key constraints.
>   **However ,you must tell OpenJPA to read the existing foreign key
>   information from the database schema:**

It would seem you can force the correct ordering of the statements by either setting the following property in your OpenJPA config

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory"> value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

or by adding the org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.ForeignKey annotation to the mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "classRoom", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.ForeignKey
protected Collection<Desk> desks;
```

See also:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1936