# Insert order of JPA entity with compound EmbeddedId (an EmbeddedId that contains another EmbeddedId)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa, websphere-8

I'm working on a project in WebSphere 8.5.5 (OpenJPA 2.2.3) that needs to cascade creation and merging through a large JPA annotated entity model.  We are having a very specific problem when merging grand-children either by calling EntityManager.merge() on the grand-parent or by the triggered flush at the commit of a transaction.  Here are the details:

Relevant portion of entity mappings:

1. EntityA has a oneToMany to EntityB
2. EntityB has a oneToMany to EntityC
3. EntityC has a oneToMany to EntityD

All have bidirectional mappings.  Entity A and B have single column primary keys.  Entity C has a composite primary key that includes a foreign key to the primary key of Entity B.  Entity D has a composite key that includes the composite key of Entity C.  Please see the mappings below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
public class EntityA extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TABLE_A_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_A_ID_GEN", sequenceName="TABLE_A_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="TABLE_A_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="entityA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntityB> entityBList;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TableB")
public class EntityB extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TABLE_B_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_B_ID_GEN", sequenceName="TABLE_B_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="TABLE_B_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="TABLE_A_ID")
    private EntityA entityA;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="entityB", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntityC> entityCList;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TableC")
public class EntityC extends BaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityC_PK id = new EntityC_PK();

    @MapsId("entityB_Id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="TABLE_B_ID")
    private EntityB entityB;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="entityC", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntityD> entityDList;

    ...

}

@Embeddable
public class EntityC_PK implements BaseComponent {

    @Column(name="TABLE_B_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer entityB_Id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TABLE_C_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_C_ID_GEN", sequenceName="TABLE_C_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="TABLE_C_ID")
    private Integer entityC_Id;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_D")
public class EntityD extends BaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityD_PK id = new EntityD_PK();

    @MapsId("entityC_Id")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_B_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_C_ID")})
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private EntityC entityC;

    ...

}

@Embeddable
public class EntityD_PK implements BaseComponent {

    @Embedded
    private EntityC_PK entityC_Id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TABLE_D_ID_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="TABLE_D_ID_GEN", sequenceName="TABLE_D_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="TABLE_D_ID")
    private Integer entity_id;

    ...

}
```

What Works:

You can call an EntityManager.persist() on Entity A (with all the children attached) and the model will cascade the persist correctly.

What Doesn't Work:

If you instantiate Entity A and call EntityManager.persist(entityA) and THEN add the children, grand-children, etc. when you EntityManager.merge(entityA) (or allow the implicit merge upon committing the transaction) it will fail to execute the INSERT statements in the correct order.  To make things more confusing the order of the INSERTS is not consistent across repeat executions of unit tests.  It fails by attempting to insert Entity D before Entity C.

The Question:

How to we correct the JPA annotations to enforce the correct insert order (and update/delete) upon merge?

EDIT 1:
The insert/delete order is critical because the database enforces the foreign key relationships with constraints.

Comment: See my answer here which may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024310/openjpa-nested-onetomany-relationships-merge-issue/39025865#39025865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first state (and maybe I'm stating the obvious, sorry) that you should review the JPA spec for your scenarios.......embedables sometimes have differently rules about them.  Next, you state 'EntityManager.create()', but I think you meant .persist?  You later talk about merge so maybe you mean .merge?  Either way, I'd suggest you stick with .persist if you want to persist new entities rather than a merge.  While it is not illegal, merge is typically for merging detached entities, etc.

With that out of the way, let me get at the heart of your question and give you a property which might help with your order.  You didn't state in your text if your ddl contains a foreign key constraint.  Since you are concerned with order, I'd assume you have such a constraint.  If you do, OpenJPA knows nothing about this constraint, and as such, will not know to order things appropriately.  By default, you can't depend on the order of SQL, and the randomness of the ordering is exactly what I expect.  However, if you need things to be order in such a way as to support an FK constraint, then you need to allow OpenJPA to 'learn' about your constraint.  To do that, you need to set this property in your persistence.xml file (or you can set it as a JVM custom property):

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
```

This property allows OpenJPA to inspect your schema and in so doing it can learn about your FK constraint.  With that knowledge, OpenJPA can properly order SQL.

Finally, if you don't have an FK constraint, but you want to order the SQL in a certain way, then you might need to use this:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order"/>
```

Do not, and I repeat do not use both of these properties together.  It can have odd side effects.  Please focus on the SchemaFactory property first, and then if it doesn't help try UpdateManager.   The operation-order tells OpenJPA to order SQL based on how your persist your entities, or in other words, the order of operations.  This might actually not be overly helpful to your situation since you persist A and expect everything else to be cascaded (OpenJPA would likely persist A first, but when it comes to B and C, it is a crapshoot which will go first).  However, if you persisted A, then C, then B, the SQL should go in order of inserting A, C, then B with "operation-order" set.

Comment: Thank you Heath for your helpful answer.  I found more information that is exactly in line with your solutions. [link](http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Inconsistent-execution-order-of-INSERT-statements-using-cascading-persist-td678745.html).  The one option you didn't mention was the use of OpenJPA's @ForeignKey annotation to flag which relationships have foreign keys and require a specific insert order.

Comment: Thanks!  I deliberately left that out (maybe I shouldn't have).  There are two concerns with OpenJPA's '@ForeignKey': 1) it is propriety.  2) It puts the onus on the developer to put '@ForeignKey' in all the right spots (miss one spot, and all bets are off).  In your case with a few classes no big deal, but in a large app it makes things harder.  I wouldn't say to not use '@FK', but I'd seriously consider using a one line property (no code changes) over adding '@FK' to the right spots across your domain model.  Good luck and enjoy!