# OpenJPA: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, constraints

I got another Problem with OpenJPA.
I am trying to delete an entry from the database, but every time I try I get an ErrorMessage like the one in the Header.

The delation of the entry does indeed violate some constraints, but I red that there is a way to let JPA delete those dependent entries automatically before deleting the actual targeted one.

I tried it with the cascade=CascadeType.Remove Attribute in the corresponding @ManyToOne-Annotations and the orphanRemoval=true Attribute int the @OneToMany-Annotations, but it didnt help.

I would like to avoid deleting those entries by myself, because I got not that much time left to implement this feature and still plenty of other things to do.

Do I need to set another property in the persistence.xml or something like that? I dont really get what I am doing wrong.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "x", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<SomeClass> class;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade=CascadeType.Remove)
private SomeClass class;
```

Here my persistence.xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="unit-name">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>Class1</class>
    <class>Class2</class>
    <class>Class3</class>
    <class>Class4</class>
    <class>Class5</class>
    <class>Class6</class>
    <class>Class7</class>
    <class>Class8</class>
    <class>Class9</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults" value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scheme"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="user"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In mysql you can temporarily drop key constraints whilst you delete a particular record by set foreign_key_checks=0, then after switch it back by set foreign_key_checks=1

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Im currently using mysql for testing but its going to be another DB as soon as the application is finished and dont know which it is going to be. This is the reason why I am using JPA in the first place.

Comment: ok, was the syntax or any use? I know i always needed it when messing with keys in mysql due to the order they are set up in

Comment: Im sorry I dont really get what you are trying to say, which syntax do you mean? The one of my JPQL-Query? It did work as long as I was deleting Objects which were not being referenced in any other table.

Comment: set foreign_key_checks=0

Comment: Im really sorry, but I still dont understand what you are trying to say. I can use "set foreign_key_checks=0" in MySQL to disable Constraints I get that, but what do you  want me to do with that? For DB-independence I am using JPQL only and let JPA generate the corresponding SQL-Queries. Despite that this command seems to  be MySQL exclusive so I cant use it either way, or am I wrong? Im sorry i really dont want to bug you, but I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: well the error message you have is mysql related. You have either not set up the key correctly or you're trying to delete data that is part of a foreign key

Comment: Yeah, of course the data I try to delete is a foreign key in another table, the idea is to delete those keys before deleting the original entry. And that is what the CascadeType.Remove value of the cascade attribute is good for or not? At least thats how I get it from this article: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete. Did I misunderstand that? Sometimes Im still struggeling to understand english texts.

Comment: what im saying is you may need to incorporate set foreign_key_checks=0 into the mysql side for it to be possible

Comment: You see to have addressed the issue with OpenJPA and foreign keys - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39025865/1356423. So that means there is something wrong with your code.  Most likely you need `cascade=CascadeType.Remove` on the `@OneToMany` and not simply orphanRemoval. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813411/1356423